# Angular-Material Autocomplete OrderBy Promise

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, angular-material

I have an md-autocomplete wired up to a list retrieved from a remote data call. I want to order my results alphabetically, but orderBy expects an array and doesn't work with a promise.

**SCENARIO 1**

This is my current implementation which works with the returned promise, but does not support orderBy.

HTML

```
<md-autocomplete
    md-no-cache="true"
    ng-model-options="{debounce: 250}"
    md-selected-item="criteria.orderByClientUser"
    md-search-text="searchText"
    md-items="item in getClientUsers(searchText)"
    md-item-text="item"
    md-min-length="0"
    placeholder="First Last">
    <md-item-template>{{item}}</md-item-template>
    <md-not-found>No matches found.</md-not-found>
</md-autocomplete>
```

Controller

```
$scope.getClientUsers = function(text) {
    if(!text) return [];
    text = text.toLowerCase();
    return clientUserProfileService.findByName(text);
}
```

ClientUserProfileService

```
service.findByName = function(name) {
    return $http.post(searchUrl, name, { withCredentials: true }).then(res => res.data);
}
```

**SCENARIO 2**

This implementation applies the data to the scope, but the function exits before the promise resolves, therefore the autocomplete list does not update.

HTML

```
<md-autocomplete
    md-no-cache="true"
    ng-model-options="{debounce: 250}"
    md-selected-item="criteria.orderByClientUser"
    md-search-text-change="getClientUsers(searchText)"
    md-items="item in userList | orderBy"
    md-item-text="item"
    md-min-length="0"
    placeholder="First Last">
    <md-item-template>{{item}}</md-item-template>
    <md-not-found>No matches found.</md-not-found>
</md-autocomplete>
```

Controller

```
$scope.userList = [];

$scope.getClientUsers = function(text) {
    if(!text) return [];
    text = text.toLowerCase();
    clientUserProfileService.findByName(text)
        .then(_.mountP($scope, "userList"));
}
```

ClientUserProfileService

```
service.findByName = function(name) {
    return $http.post(searchUrl, name, { withCredentials: true }).then(res => res.data);
}
```

Is there a way to configure the orderBy to work with a promise? Or is there a way to delay the getClientUsers from returning until the promise is resolved? This query is extremely quick, so I know I could just defer the service method and wrap it in a small timeout, but that seems like a copout.

Appreciate your help!

** **UPDATED CODE** ** - Still results in promise being returned from getClientUsers() which doesn't work with orderBy

```
Error: [orderBy:notarray]
```

HTML

```
<md-autocomplete
    md-no-cache="true"
    ng-model-options="{debounce: 250}"
    md-selected-item="criteria.orderByClientUser"
    md-search-text="searchText"
    md-items="item in getClientUsers(searchText) | orderBy"
    md-item-text="item"
    md-min-length="0"
    placeholder="First Last">
    <md-item-template>{{item}}</md-item-template>
    <md-not-found>No matches found.</md-not-found>
</md-autocomplete>
```

Controller

```
$scope.getClientUsers = function(text) {
    if(!text) return [];
    text = text.toLowerCase();
    return clientUserProfileService.findByName(text)
        .then(function (data) {
            return data;
        });
}
```

ClientUserProfileService

```
service.findByName = function(name) {
    return $http.post(searchUrl, name, { withCredentials: true }).then(res => res.data);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scenario #2 needs to return a promise:

```
//Scenario #2

$scope.userList = [];

$scope.getClientUsers = function(text) {
    if(!text) return [];
    text = text.toLowerCase();
    //vvvv return derived promise
    return clientUserProfileService.findByName(text)
      .then(function (data)
           //_.mountP($scope, "userList")
           //do something to data
           //vvvv return data to chain
           return modifiedData;
    );
}
```

> Because calling the `.then` method of a promise **returns a new derived promise**, it is easily possible to create a chain of promises. It is possible to create chains of any length and since **a promise can be resolved with another promise (which will defer its resolution further)**, it is possible to pause/defer resolution of the promises at any point in the chain. This makes it possible to implement powerful APIs.
>
> [-- AngularJS $q Service API Reference - Chaining Promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises)

---

To order the data using the AngularJS `orderBy` filter:

```
$scope.getClientUsers = function(text) {
    if(!text) return [];
    text = text.toLowerCase();
    //vvvv return derived promise
    return clientUserProfileService.findByName(text)
      .then(function (data)
           //_.mountP($scope, "userList")
           //do something to data
           var orderByData = $filter("orderBy")(data);
           //vvvv return data to chain
           return orderByData;
    );
}
```

For more information, see [AngularJS orderBy Filter API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy).

Comment: Perhaps I'm mistaken, but when I implemented this the getClientUsers method still returns a promise, not the data, which is not supported by orderBy. This was the same situation I ran into with Scenario #1. Did I misinterpret your answer? I have updated the question with my current working code